# How to loop through a dictionary to get the data stored in Sqlalchemy table?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, for-loop, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a dictionary called self.structure = {0: "xyz.php"}. I would like to store this into my Database table Structure which consists of columns (arm_id and page_url). How can I save it into the database table using a for loop? Please help as I am new to programming.
Here's my code:

```
    def init(self):
        self.lista["counter"] = 0

        self.lista["conversion"] = 0
        # Default page
        # for self.structure in Structure.query.all():
        #     print(self.structure.__dict__)
        self.structure = {0: "xyz.php"}
        struct = Structure.query.all()
        for i in struct:
            struct.self.structure.append(i)
            print("-------------", len(struct))
```

here's the code for my structure table.

```
class Structure(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'structure'

    arm_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    page_url = db.Column(db.String())

   
    def __init__(self, arm_id,page_url):
        self.arm_id = arm_id
        self.page_url = page_url
```

I tried using a forloop as above but it didn't store the data in the database..please enlighten me where I am going wrong.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to loop over the `self.structure` dict instead of over the `struct` list you query:

```py
for arm_id in self.structure:  # this is 0, 1, 2...
  new_structure = Structure(arm_id=arm_id, page_url=self.structure[arm_id])
  db.session.add(new_structure)
db.session.commit()
```

or equivalently:

```py
for arm_id, page_url in self.structure.items():
  new_structure = Structure(arm_id=arm_id, page_url=page_url)
  db.session.add(new_structure)
db.session.commit()
```

The commit is to make sure the saved changes actually stick.
Also, don't store things to `self.` if you're not using them elsewhere, use `structure` instead of `self.structure`.